# Cannot purge tailwind

Tags: ejs, tailwind-css

I am trying to purge tailwind with ejs. But when I tried to purge, I got this `Error: Could not resolve entry module (index.html)` ..

**Here is my `tailwind config.js`:**

```
module.exports = {
    purge: ["./**/*.ejs"],
    darkMode: false, // or 'media' or 'class'
    theme: {
        extend: {
            container: {
                center: true,
            },
        },
    },
    variants: {
        extend: {},
    },
    plugins: [],
}
```

**My `postcss config.js` file:**

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    tailwindcss: {},
    autoprefixer: {},
  },
}
```

**Inside my `app.js`**

```
app.set('view engine', "ejs");

app.use(express.static('public'));
```

Inside my `package.json`, I have this script:

```
"scripts": {
    "build:tailwinds": "tailwind build -i src/style.css -o public/css/style.css",
    "start": "nodemon app.js",
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build"
  },
```

**My folder structure:**
[See how my files are organized](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sxDTr.png)

How can i purge tailwind with ejs file. In ejs there are no index.html, so how can I solve the error? What I am missing out?

Answer (score 0):

Is your tailwind version updated to the latest?

Take a look at my set up, tweak things up to see if purge works for you with ejs.

***tailwind.config.js***

```html
module.exports = {
  mode: "jit",
  purge: [
    "./src/pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
    "./src/components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
  ],
```

***package.json***

```html
"tw:build": "tailwindcss build ./src/styles/global.css -o ./public/styles/global.css",
    "tw:prod": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production postcss build ./src/styles/global.css -o ./public/styles/global.css",
    "tw:watch": "onchange \"tailwind.config.js\" \"src/**/*.css\" -- npm run tw:build"
```

You can also use cssnano it's an awsome extension for purging tailwind css

***postcss.config.js***

```html
const cssnano = require("cssnano");

module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    require("tailwindcss"),
    cssnano({
      preset: "default",
    }),
    require("autoprefixer"),
  ],
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you use Tailwind v3:

> Since Tailwind no longer uses PurgeCSS under the hood, we’ve renamed
> the purge option to content to better reflect what it’s for:

**tailwind.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  content: [
    './public/**/*.html',
    './src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx,vue}',
  ],
}
```